# Range of $\sin x_1+\dots +\sin x_n$ constrained to $\cos x_1 +\dots +\cos x_n = c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've recently come up with the following problem and have no clue how to approach it:

Let $f,g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ with $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sin x_1+\dots +\sin x_n$ and $g(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \cos x_1 +\dots +\cos x_n$.

Then for all $a,b \in [-n,n]$, there exists $\vec{x} = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(\vec{x}) = a$ **and** $g(\vec{x}) = b$.

Comment: There is no way it's true as stated:  If $f(\vec{x}) = n$, then $\sin x_i = 1$ for all $i$.  Then $\cos x_i = 0$ for all $i$ so $g(\vec{x}) = 0$.  In particular, if $a = n$, then $b$ must be $0$.  For the question in your title, I don't have time to work on it, but I'd start with Lagrange multipliers.  If you can find the max and min, you find the range since the range must be connected.  (I'm not sure Lagrange multipliers would work, but it is where I'd start.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, a necessary  condition is $a^2 + b^2 \le n^2$, obtained by applying the triangle inequality to $$\exp(i x_1) + \ldots \exp(i x_n) = a + i b$$  This is sufficient in the case $n \ge 2$ (it's obviously not if $n=1$).